# jquery each vs. native for

Tags: jquery

```
var arr=[];
var k;
for(var i=0;i<5000;i++)
 arr[i]=i;

console.time("native loop");
var len=arr.length;
for(var j=0;j<len;j++)
 k=arr[j];
console.timeEnd("native loop");

console.time("jq loop");
$(arr).each(function(i,el){
 k=el;
});
console.timeEnd("jq loop");
```

It is generating, 14ms for native loop and 3ms for Jquery each.

I'm using Jquery 1.6.2. If Jquery uses native loop behind the scene, then how come, this is possible??

Comment: sounds like something is wrong - did you run that benchmakr multiple times to proove the results? clould you please try it with more iterations (500k)?

Comment: That doesn't match my results, which browser and how many times did you run your benchmark? http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/8V6pk/

Comment: what happens when you run the each first

Comment: for 50000, it's native-172ms and jquery-28ms and for 500000, it's native -1371ms and jquery-292ms on chromium 14 on ubuntu

Comment: after putting jquery each first, it's giving jquery-3ms and native-16ms

Comment: The statistics here is confirming your observation http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loop/38

Comment: Try this test - http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-cannot-be-faster-than-the-native-for-loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would think that it has to do with the scope of your index variable -- your `j` variable is a global, which is about the slowest case of variable access. Every time that your loop has to reference j, it needs to check all the way up the scope chain, back to the global object, and then get the variable value from there.

I get similar numbers to you in my console (Chrome, OS X -- 13-15ms for the for loop, 3-4ms for jQuery).

But, if I do this:

```
(function() {
    console.time("native loop with function scope");
    var len=arr.length;
    for(var j=0;j++<len;)
        k=arr[j];
    console.timeEnd("native loop with function scope");})()
```

It executes in just 5ms.

The difference in this case is that `j` is a function-local variable, available immediately in the first place the JavaScript engine looks for variables. `len` is similarly local; the only globals in this case are `k` and `arr`.

To get even more speed out of this, make k a function-scope variable, and pass in `arr` as a parameter:

```
(function(arr) {
    console.time("native loop 2");
    var len=arr.length, k;
    for(var j=0;j++<len;)
        k=arr[j];
    console.timeEnd("native loop 2");})(arr)

> native loop 2: 0ms
```

Well, that's a bit too fast now. Maybe arr should be bigger:

```
var arr=[];
for(var i=0;i<50000;i++)
    arr[i]=i;

[Try again...]
> native loop 2: 1ms
```

That slowed it down a bit.

With a 500k-element array, this code runs in 4ms in the JavaScript console on my machine. At 5M, it takes 36ms.

You should also note that you aren't using a raw jQuery.each() call -- you are first wrapping your array in $(), creating a jQuery object, and then calling .each on that. A fairer test might be to run

```
$.each(arr, function(i,el){
    k=el;
});
```

That should be pretty close to the timing of the second example above. jQuery adds a bit of overhead; checking the types of its arguments, but after that it runs a pretty tight loop.

Comment: This is somewhat solving the problem. This thing is working in firefox 8 on my machine, but on chromium, the stats are same. In that too, it's not effective on large input set. Have you tried it on 500000?

Comment: On 500000, it ran in 4ms, which was about the same time as the original 5000-element jQuery test. At that point, I figured that most of the jQuery time was spent converting the array into a wrapped jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/javascript-for-loop-vs-jquery-each.html

Comment: He is stating something else. jQuery is faster here, and not native code like in your link.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.georgepaterson.com/2011/08/30/javascript-performance-jquery-each-and-each-versus-alternatives/`jQuery.each` is designed to iterate over arrays and array like objects. 
Opposite result from your Question.see link
http://jsfiddle.net/martinaglv/NcRsV/